# How exactly accept() method is blocked until a connection is made?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

From [java.net.ServerSocket#accept()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/ServerSocket.java#ServerSocket.accept%28%29):

> ```
> public Socket accept() throws IOException
> ```
>
> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The
>   method blocks until a connection is made.

I don't understand how exactly execution of the method stops until a connection is made. I searched through source code but I don't see any `while(true)` loops or `wait/notify`.

I googled the question but can't find an explanation how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `PlainSocketImpl` you have the `native void socketAccept(SocketImpl s) throws IOException;` method. So it blocks in native code, and you don't need to care how it's done.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure about this, but I think that accept() does an `accept` system call through some native lib (Some C or C++ library maybe). The `accept` system call will then block waiting for an incoming connection that is suitable. At this point, it is not Java dependent, it is dependent from how each OS implements this.